# Is there a way to emulate key presses on Windows with low latency?

Tags: c++, windows, input

I am trying to control a windows application through c++. This is my code for mouse clicks:

```
// info is a WINDOWINFO struct retrieved with GetWindowInfo()

void click(int x, int y) {
    // move mouse to given position plus the position of the top left corner of the window
    SetCursorPos(info.rcWindow.left + x, info.rcWindow.top + y)

    INPUT    Input = { 0 };
    // left mouse button down 
    Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    ::SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));

    // left mouse button up
    ::ZeroMemory(&Input, sizeof(INPUT));
    Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    ::SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

It works, but the latency (~120ms) is too great for my project. Is there a way to reduce it? I only need to control a single window, so the call to the operating system seems excessive, but I couldn't find any examples of directly injecting mouse input to a window online.

Comment: How are you measuring the latency?  I would not expect this to take 200ms (unless the target application is slow, perhaps).

Comment: @PaulSanders Yup, it was too high, this time I actually measured it instead of eyeballing.

Comment: How is the function being called? Is the function call being looped?

Comment: Do you get the same latency with Notepad? Perhaps the target program is just slow to process input.

Comment: Calling `SendInput()` with `nInputs=1` and no delays between multiple events is a logic bug in your code. The whole benefit of `SendInput()` vs `mouse_event()` is the ability to *atomically* send multiple events in 1 function call. Do so. Also, when controlling other apps, you generally should be using UI Automation APIs instead of simulating user input.

Comment: If you find the call to the OS to be excessive, it's rather inconclusive to do it twice. Even moreso when the only reason for the second call is to introduce a window for a race condition. The documentation explains why you should not pass a single `INPUT` structure per call in this case.